# Time difference with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a variable called `df` with three colums with the following data in `datetime64`:

| start_time | end_time | extra_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 09:53:02 | 2022-12-05 09:53:21 | 1 days 23:30:15 |

I want to add a 4th column saying that if extra_time is positive, then it's Intime. Otherwise, it's offtime.

I tried using `for` like this:

```
for extra_time in df:
 if extra_time >= 0:
   df['intime'] == True
 else:
   df['intime'] == False
```

And I get the following:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I know that my result contains string and numbers, such as:

```
0         1 days 23:30:15
```

The thing is that I'm out of ideas on how to proceed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Convert to `timedelta`

```
df["extra_time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["extra_time"]).dt.total_seconds()
df["intime"] = df["extra_time"] >= 0
```

output:

```
            start_time             end_time  extra_time  intime
0  2022-12-01 09:53:02  2022-12-05 09:53:21    171015.0    True
1  2022-12-01 10:53:02  2022-12-02 10:53:21     -1785.0   False
```